# Undeclared GTK_OBJECT during g++ compilation

Tags: g++, gtk

I get errors during compilation of a GTK+ application saying I have undeclared functions/definitions (I believe GTK_OBJECT might be a definition in a header file). This is my code (main.c):

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget* w, GdkEventAny* e, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Create widgets
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); 

    //Initialize widgets
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    //Configure widgets
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello World");

    //Display widgets
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    //Set up signals
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget* w, GdkEventAny* e, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
    turn FALSE;
}
```

I am using the following command in bash:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o binary
```

I do have the developer version of gtk+ 3.0 installed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is the error message I get:

```
main.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.c:21:41: error: ‘GTK_OBJECT’ was not declared in this scope
     gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
                                         ^
main.c:21:91: error: ‘GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC’ was not declared in this scope
     gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
                                                                                           ^
main.c:21:98: error: ‘gtk_signal_connect’ was not declared in this scope
     gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from main.c:1:
main.c: In function ‘gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget*, GdkEventAny*, gpointer)’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:229:17: error: ‘turn’ was not declared in this scope
 #define FALSE (0)
                 ^
main.c:29:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘FALSE’
     turn FALSE;
          ^
```

Comment: Please copy paste the error you're getting, so we can see the same thing you see.

Comment: Done. I added it to my post.

Comment: `GTK_OBJECT()` and `GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC()` are GTK+ 2. You're compiling with GTK+ 3. Which do you want to use, 2 or 3?

Comment: I want to use 3. I was following examples in books that was put up as documentation on www.gtk.org, but they must have been a bit dated.

Comment: I still have error messages. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by myself, but it was difficult to find out how. I gave the wrong order of arguments to g++ and missed an argument as well. This is the bash command that worked for me:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o binary `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```